# G1 doesn't process soft references

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

Here is my simple gc test:

```
public class Main {

  static class Data {
    public long[] l = new long[100];
  }

  static List<SoftReference<Data>> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long i = 0;

    while (true) {
      list.add(new SoftReference<>(new Data()));
      ++i;
      if (i % 1000 == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        if (i % 1_000_000 == 0)
          sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }

  static void sleep(long millis) {
    try { Thread.sleep(millis); } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
  }
}
```

Using these args (G1 enabled):

```
java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xloggc:jvm.log -XX:+UseG1GC 
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=5 Main
```

I grep the output:

```
grep -E "(Full|GC cleanup)" jvm.log
```

and get something like this:

```
0.564: [GC cleanup 277M->277M(2048M), 0.0009922 secs]
0.879: [GC cleanup 443M->442M(2048M), 0.0009396 secs]
1.676: [GC cleanup 859M->856M(2048M), 0.0008681 secs]
3.530: [GC cleanup 1324M->1320M(2048M), 0.0012422 secs]
4.838: [GC cleanup 1711M->1707M(2048M), 0.0010601 secs]
6.334: [Full GC 2047M->102M(2048M), 1.2659685 secs]
8.322: [GC cleanup 534M->534M(2048M), 0.0009528 secs]
11.250: [GC cleanup 1460M->1450M(2048M), 0.0011207 secs]
13.499: [Full GC 2046M->512M(2048M), 1.3534848 secs]
```

It seems that soft references were collected during ParallelGc's full collections while concurrent collections were almost useless. Heap dumps from VisualVm also prove this version.

Do I miss something or it is a bug in G1?

Checked on 1.7.0_51-b13 and 1.8.0_45-b15 x64.

Comment: Soft references will behave really strangely and nondeterministically.  Forcing the GC to do anything with them is hard or impossible.

Comment: It appears that the issue is already in Oracle bugtracker, and it won't be closed any time soon: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6912889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are confusing with weak references?

The GC is not forced to collect soft references, unless it finds itself under severe memory pressure.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) for more information.

In particular, notice the following quote from the documentation:

> Soft reference objects, which are cleared at the **discretion** of the garbage collector in response to memory demand.

The only real guarantee the documentation offers is as follows:

> All soft references to softly-reachable objects are guaranteed to have been cleared before the virtual machine throws an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds logical.

Answer (score 1):

There is `-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=` (default=1000) that governs the collection rate of soft references. Lower values make it collect them faster.

I don't know how it interacts with G1's regions. It's possible that some regions are rarely touched and thus their soft references don't get taken into account.

As @sstan mentioned WeakReferences may offer somewhat more predictable behavior at the expense of much shorter lifetimes of the references.

---

Another problem is that you do not clear the list of nulled-out softreference objects. If you register the refs with a [reference queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html), poll that queue during after the sleep(1000) for references and remove them from the list you should not run out of memory.
For faster lookup a set might be more suitable than a list.

Comment: Unfortunately, SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB doesn't help in getting rid of full gcs